# sourceText value to be the layer index number according to current time indicator

Tags: after-effects

Is there any way I could use a text layer and set it's source text value to be the layer index number of the visible layer or where AE's current time indicator is (CTI) during ram preview?

Answer (score 1):

This will indicate the current time and the index of the first active layer:

```
var comp = app.project.activeItem;
var layer = comp.layers.addText("");
layer.text.sourceText.expression = 
"""idx = "-";
N = thisComp.numLayers;
for (i=1; i<=N; i++){
    if (i===index) continue;
    if (thisComp.layer(i).active){idx = i; break;};
    };
line2 = "Active Layer : " + idx;
line1 = "CTI : " + timeToCurrentFormat(time);
line1 + "\r" + line2;"""
```

(This is to be used from a script. To use directly inside After Effects, copy paste what's between triple quotes in the text expression box).